# how to set validator with QDoubleValidator? (QValidator)

Tags: c++, c, qt

I now have a class called EditBox which inherit from Qwidget and QTextEdit

And I'm trying to set a validator to this text edit box....

```
EditBox manbox;
```

How do I set up a validator to 0~100? with 2 decimal point?

I've tried

```
QDoubleValidator *testQD = new QDoubleValidator(manbox);
testQD->setRange(0.00,100.00,2);

QLineEdit *sb1 = new QLineEdit( manbox );
sb1->setValidator(testQD);
```

but seems not working. Any where went wrong?

Or please guide me somewhere i can find full tutorial for this one.
Thanks!

Comment: You start by saying your class inherits QTextEdit, but then you are setting a validator on a QLineEdit. Which is it? Also, can you please be more specific about "seems not working"?

Comment: What does it mean that `EditBox` inherits after QWidget and QTextEdit? Does it use multiple inheritance? You can't set validator on QTextEdit object. In your example validator is set for `sb1` QLineEdit. You only set up `manbox` for its parent.

Answer (score 3):

You can't set a validator for a `QTextEdit`, it only works for `QLineEdit` (and input widgets containing a `QLineEdit` like `QSpinBox`, `QComboBox`...).

If you only need one line, and restrict the content to a number, you could as well replace the `QTextEdit` in your class `EditBox` by a `QLineEdit` or a `QDoubleSpinBox`.